# DirectX Exception handling

Tags: c++, exception, directx

I'm following the rastertek tutorial on DirectX while also studying Exception-Safety in Generic Components by David Abrahams (http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html).

Why (to the best of anyone's knowledge) is the exception handling set up the way it is in the rastertek tutorial and what level of protection does it offer?

For instance:

```
mhresult = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, 0, &mfeatureLevel, 1,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &mswapChainDesc, &mswapChain, &mdevice, NULL, &mdeviceContext);

if (FAILED(mhresult))
{
    return false;
}
```

if an unhandled exception occurs in the call to CreateDevice won't the program crash before we check the result of mhresult?

Does it make a difference whether we're calling a method with an HResult return value or just a boolean?

```
result = mEstablishHW();
if (!result)
{
    return false;
}
```

Is there an alternative approach that would provide strong exception safety without a performance impact?

Comment: can you clarify? there is no exception handling here. Also the 2 code samples are functionally equal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DirectX is a [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)-based API. And exceptions are not allowed to cross COM boundary. So no DirectX function exists that ever throw. Instead, they use C-style return codes, which are called [HRESULT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT), to indicate errors.

To effectively work with DirectX, obviously you should learn at least some basics of COM. But here are tips to start with, to make your initial code safer and to simplify debugging:

- Always always always check return code. It doesn't mean you should write `if/else` each time. Write a macro that will check `HRESULT`, break a debugger in case of "not `S_OK`", and tell you a file, line and function where it happened. You could also convert `HRESULT` to readable string and output it (in console).
- It is a good idea, to check output objects if they are valid (i.e. not "`NULL`"): `mswapChain`, `mdevice`, `mdeviceContext` in your example.
- Use DirectX debug layer: [D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj200584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Use Graphics diagnostics tools: [one is built into Visual Studio since 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh315751.aspx), [Nvidia Nsight](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition) is very good too
- Finally, read the docs! MSDN isn't perfect, but [DirectX docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476080%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are pretty well-written.

Anyway, DirectX is not the API to start to learn exception safety. Maybe Standard library (like trying to write proper `swap` function for your classes) or Boost (like filesystem) will work better for that purpose.

Comment: Exactly the kind of info I was looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DirectX doesn't use exceptions to report errors or anything else. The DirectX interfaces are meant to be compiler agnostic and using C++ exceptions would tie their use to a specific compiler because of ABI differences. Even different versions Microsoft C++ would be incompatible because of ABI differences.

Since most DirectX methods and functions return an `HRESULT` value, you'll want to check for errors like in your first example. You can then throw an exception in your own code if that makes sense for your project.

Comment: Alright so I think I get it then: Essentially calling DirectX provides a no-throw guarantee right? A correct call to DirectX won't cause an application crash but will instead return a S_OK or a FAILED. However; ignoring a FAILED returned to your _own_ code could potentially cause an exception when your application tries to move on to the next directx call, right?

Comment: Yes, you can't ignore a failure and go on as if the call succeeded. In your first example, none of the output parameters (`mswapChain mdevice mdeviceContext`) will be set if it fails, so trying to use them after a failure will likely cause a crash. However you continue to use a Direct3D interface after it fails as if the failing operation was never performed. In your first example you could try again with different parameters if the first call fails.