# D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain Fails to succeed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx, directx-11, direct3d

I currently have a for loop which should be broken out of once hr has succeeded however it's not succeeding, which is causing me problems later down the line.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;

#ifdef _DEBUG
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] =
    {
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
    };

    UINT numDriverTypes = ARRAYSIZE(driverTypes);

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    };

 UINT numFeatureLevels = ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels);

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(sd));
    sd.BufferCount = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = _WindowWidth;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = _WindowHeight;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = _hWnd;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;    
for (UINT driverTypeIndex = 0; driverTypeIndex < numDriverTypes; driverTypeIndex++)
        {
            _driverType = driverTypes[driverTypeIndex];
            hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(nullptr, _driverType, nullptr, createDeviceFlags, featureLevels, numFeatureLevels,
                                               D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sd, &_pSwapChain, &_pd3dDevice, &_featureLevel, &_pImmediateContext);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                break;
        }
```

Clearly D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain within the for loop is returning a value other than succeeded and the wierd thing is, that when I run this program on another PC it works fine! I've updated all my drivers, restarted my PC and uninstalled all anti-virus software but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: So what is the value it's returning?  Also, is `_DEBUG` defined?  Not all systems have the prerequisite SDKLayers installed which are required for the `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` flag to work.

Comment: The value is returning FAILED after I check it with "if (FAILED(hr))". I'm not sure where this would be defined, are you talking about what I've written at the top? "#ifdef _DEBUG
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif"

Comment: Yes, are you passing the `DEBUG` flag in `createDeviceFlags`?

Comment: Yeah, I hit createDeviceFlags  when I place a breakpoint there

Comment: what error number is contained in hr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally Fixed the problem.

Microsoft released an update for Windows 10 that automatically removes support for DirectX11. It has to be re-enabled. If anyone runs into this issue in Windows 10, to re-enable DirectX11 go to:

Settings -> Apps -> Manage -> Add extra graphics support

(apparently I need to wait 21 hours to accept my own answer...)

Comment: DirectX 11 is present on Windows 10. It is the debug layer (as I noted in my answer) that is missing. Both the DirectX 11 and DirectX 12 runtimes are always present on Windows 10, as is the WARP11 device. The DEBUG device for DirectX 11, the DEBUG device for DirectX 12, and WARP12 require the _Graphics Tools_ feature-on-demand to be installed. The FOD is specific to your build #, and upgrading to a new build # invalidates the FOD.

Comment: For recent Windows (1903), this is located in "Settings / Apps & Features / Optional Features / Graphic Tools (137M 'This adds DirectX Graphics Tools support')" but it seems something has installed it automatically... (Visual Studio ? SDK ?)

Answer (score 4):

You have not stated which OS you are using, but the most likely cause of the failure is that your system does not have the correct Direct3D SDK Debug Layer installed. In this case, if you attempt to create a device with `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` it will fail. A quick test is if your Release build succeeds in creating the device, but your Debug builds does not.

To get the correct SDK layers installed for your OS:

- **Windows 7 RTM** -> the legacy DirectX SDK will do it
- **Windows 7 SP1** with the [KB2670838](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/14/directx-11-1-and-windows-7.aspx) update (aka DirectX 11.1) -> you have to install the Windows 8.x SDK; the legacy DirectX SDK version is out of date
- **Windows 8** or **Windows 8.1** -> The Windows 8.x SDK installs it
- **Windows 10** -> This is now a [Feature On Demand](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/31/visual-studio-2015-and-graphics-tools-for-windows-10.aspx) for Windows 10. Note that if you upgraded from 10240 to 10586, then you need to re-enable the FOD.

See [Direct3D SDK Debug Layer Tricks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx)

The other possibility is that your system does not have a Feature Level 10.0 or later video card, but given the code tries to use WARP it would have worked with that.

See [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device.aspx)

> You should take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and the [Direct3D Win32 Game Template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As you said, same code is running perfect on other machine, that means either you have issue in your gpu, try to run using WARP or Reference device, remove D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE from list and try again.

Try it using

```
D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] =
    {
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
    };
```

and kindly read details about driver types here [What's the difference between WARP drivers,reference drivers and software drivers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703228/whats-the-difference-between-warp-drivers-reference-drivers-and-software-driver)

Answer (score -1):

From my own meager understanding of DX11 and COM:

1. As per rastertek.com, here is a relevant code snippet and explanation:

> Note that if the user does not have a DirectX 11 video card this function call will fail to create the device and device context. Also if you are testing DirectX 11 functionality yourself and don't have a DirectX 11 video card then you can replace D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE with D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE and DirectX will use your CPU to draw instead of the video card hardware. Note that this runs 1/1000 the speed but it is good for people who don't have DirectX 11 video cards yet on all their machines.

```
// Create the swap chain, Direct3D device, and Direct3D device context.
result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, 0, &featureLevel, 1, 
                       D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, &m_device, NULL, &m_deviceContext);
if(FAILED(result))
{
    return false;
}
```

Try changing the driver type flag to D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE for debug purposes. If that works, you probably do not have a DX11 GPU.

2. As per another stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714503/directx-exception-handling), the selected answer might be of some future use to you and also MSDN has an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476174(v=vs.85).aspx) on DX11 HRESULT return codes and COM [error handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ff485842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

The best thing you can do right now is to find the value of the HRESULT by passing each enum from the MSDN article into an if statement. Eg:

```
if (hr == E_OUTOFMEMORY) {
//do whatever
}
```

Comment: OP's code already tries to create a device on HW, WARP, and Ref, and permits feature level 10.  Independent of hardware support, this should generally succeed when it hits the FL 10.1 + WARP combination.